# ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler using Brew

Tags: python, macos, ssl

I'm having some troubles while setting up my python env... I installed python over **brew** but when I try to install something with easy_install or pip I get this errors, in this example i tried to install an package with pip...

I'm using a Macbook with Mavericks, python 2.7.8...

Thank you! :)

```
$ sudo pip install test
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 356, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2439, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2155, in load
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip.util import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.distlib import version
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/distlib/version.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .compat import string_types
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/distlib/compat.py", line 31, in <module>
    from urllib2 import (Request, urlopen, URLError, HTTPError,
ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler
```

**brew list python**

```
Joao-Carreira-Macbook-Pro:Desktop joaocarreira$ brew list python
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/2to3
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/2to3-2
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/2to3-2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/easy_install
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/easy_install-2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/idle
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/idle2
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/idle2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/pip
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/pip2
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/pip2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/pydoc
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/pydoc2
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/pydoc2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/python
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/python-config
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/python2
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/python2-config
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/python2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/python2.7-config
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/pythonw
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/pythonw2
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/pythonw2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/smtpd.py
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/smtpd2.7.py
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/bin/smtpd2.py
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/ (3666 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/IDLE.app/Contents/ (8 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/libexec/pip/ (407 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/libexec/setuptools/ (252 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Python Launcher.app/Contents/ (17 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/share/man/ (3 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/share/python/ (317 files)
```

**brew install -vd python**

```
Joao-Carreira-Macbook-Pro:Desktop joaocarreira$ brew install -vd python 
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb (Formulary::StandardLoader): loading /usr/local/Library/Formula/python.rb
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb (Formulary::StandardLoader): loading /usr/local/Library/Formula/pkg-config.rb
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb (Formulary::StandardLoader): loading /usr/local/Library/Formula/readline.rb
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb (Formulary::StandardLoader): loading /usr/local/Library/Formula/sqlite.rb
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb (Formulary::StandardLoader): loading /usr/local/Library/Formula/gdbm.rb
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb (Formulary::StandardLoader): loading /usr/local/Library/Formula/openssl.rb
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb (Formulary::StandardLoader): loading /usr/local/Library/Formula/makedepend.rb
Warning: python-2.7.8 already installed, it's just not linked
```

Comment: You have no SSL support; how exactly did you install Python with `brew`? The current `python` formula pulls in OpenSSL correctly, for example and you should not see this problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I did: brew install python

Comment: Something went rather wrong there. I just tried and it does correctly install OpenSSL support. Try out `brew doctor` to see if there are any problems. What does `brew list openssl` and `brew list python` show (maybe add the output for those in your question)?

Comment: You could try to `brew uninstall python`, then `brew install -vd python` to show the full troubleshooting output.

Comment: Joao-Carreira-Macbook-Pro:Desktop joaocarreira$ brew list openssl
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1h/bin/c_rehash
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1h/bin/openssl
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1h/include/openssl/ (75 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1h/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1h/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1h/lib/engines/ (12 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1h/lib/pkgconfig/ (3 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1h/lib/ (4 other files)
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1h/share/man/ (1126 files)

Comment: I have 3667 files in `python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/`; one more than you have. What does reinstalling `python` with `-vd` produce?

Comment: It installs normally, but in the middle of th installation it shows again this errors: ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found. 
But it installs anyway...

Comment: Yes, those errors mean that Python is not finding the (right?) OpenSSL library. Does `brew doctor` give anything?

Comment: Nop, brew doctor says: "Your system is ready to brew."

Comment: I also asked for the output of `brew install -vd python`; there is not enough info here to see why Python is not picking up the homebrew OpenSSL library.

Comment: I edited the post again, because the log is to long

Comment: But your output indicates you did not uninstall first. If the log is too long, remove the `brew list` outputs as they are not very helpful here. If it still then doesn't fit, use a Gist or Pastie, we can then extract the relevant parts.

Comment: Its here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/51ff4551e679354be575

Comment: Your output shows that an already downloaded [Bottle](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Bottles) is used; it is that bottle that must be corrupted or otherwise broken. My copy has a `sha1sum` output of `11c4ad33f1a0ec2a9dee025f246e67a0783e8bdb`, perhaps yours differs or otherwise fails to work on your system. Please uninstall and try again with `brew install --build-from-source python`. If the SHA1 of your bottle differs, delete it (`rm /Library/Caches/Homebrew/python-2.7.8.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz`) and try installing again without the `--build-from-source` to force a re-download.

Comment: I ended up following the instructions in the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372911/python-pip-error-on-osx) after trying the suggestions in the comments above. That worked for me.

Comment: The top answer here fixed it for me:

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126830/how-to-upgrade-openssl-in-os-x/126832#126832

Comment: Answered on sister site http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126830/how-to-upgrade-openssl-in-os-x/126832#126832

Answer (score 0):

You should reinstall python via brew with --with-brewed-openssl after installing openssl with brew (`brew install openssl`) and correctly linking it `brew link openssl`.