# python/pip error on osx

Tags: python, macos

I've recently purchased a new hard drive and installed a clean copy of OS X Mavericks. I installed python using homebrew and i need to create a python virtual environment. But when ever i try to run any command using pip, I get this error. I haven't been able to find a solution online for this problem. Any reference would be appreciated. Here is the error I'm getting.

```
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 356, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2439, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2155, in load
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip.util import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.distlib import version
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/distlib/version.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .compat import string_types
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/distlib/compat.py", line 31, in <module>
    from urllib2 import (Request, urlopen, URLError, HTTPError,
ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler
```

If you need any extra information from me let me know, this is my first time posting a question here. Thanks.

Comment: you need to install `openssl`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Ok I found out [online](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/22816#issuecomment-39017095) that these errors are related to openssl. But i already had openssl installed. A little more research and I tried the following and it solved the issue for me. Here's my solution in case you get the same error.

```
brew install openssl
brew link openssl --force
brew uninstall python
brew install python --with-brewed-openssl
```

Comment: For me `brew reinstall python` was enough (I got it from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688034/importerror-cannot-import-name-httpshandler-using-pip).

Comment: on el capitan `brew link openssl --force` was enough (after ensuring openssl was installed in the first place) for me.

Comment: on OSX 10.11.3 with and and updated Homebrew ```Homebrew >1.0.0 (no git repository)
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 2775; last commit 2016-09-22)``` I get the following error message when trying to force link openssl ```Warning: Refusing to link: openssl
Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure,
deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl.
Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib```

Comment: I manage to fix the problem by manually linking :
brew update    
brew install openssl    
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/    
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/

Comment: Thank you kind sir.

Comment: invalid option: --with-brewed-openssl

Comment: Noob here. After running `brew link openssl --force` I get a message `Warning: Refusing to link macOS-provided software: openssl@1.1
If you need to have openssl@1.1 first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"

For pkg-config to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"`. Would be glad for any help

Comment: `brew reinstall python@2` worked for me and was sufficient. Thanks...

Comment: Note: You may have to explicitly state the python version. ex: `brew uninstall pyhon2`. The Google Cloud SDK, for example, looks for python 2 binaries first, regardless of where your `python` command is symlinked.

Answer (score 3):

The `brew install openssl` solution above did not work for with using Python 3. Then I realized that I had installed Python *3.4.2* but the "No HTTPSHandler" exception was looking in `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/...`.

After deleting all older Python 3 paths and reinstalling virtualenv it works again:

```
pip3 uninstall virtualenv
pip3 install virtualenv
```

Note that `install --upgrade` didn't work, needs to be uninstalled first.

Answer (score 3):

I had to manually add library linking to make it works because I had error with `brew link openssl --force`

```
brew update    
brew install openssl    
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/    
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
brew uninstall python
brew install python --with-brewed-openssl
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error on 10.10 when trying to install pygame. Fixed it by brew remove python3 then installed python3.4.2 from python.org along with active state tcl.

Error gone
then
pip3 install virtualenv

You will get a message with brew doctor
Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

Homebrew only supports building against the System-provided Python or a
brewed Python. In particular, Pythons installed to /Library can interfere
with other software installs.

Which for me doesn't matter as I prefer to stick with python.org installs so python is the same across platforms rather than differing in brew (have run into problems before)