# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED on pip3 install

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, ssl-certificate

I am working on a fork of a google hangout bot (https://github.com/hangoutsbot/hangoutsbot), and everything was working great, and one day it just broke now whenever I do `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` I get the this response:

```
Collecting      git+https://github.com/tdryer/hangups.git@84c6a20a24bede2fa41ffd54fda510e453f080dc (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Cloning https://github.com/tdryer/hangups.git (to 84c6a20a24bede2fa41ffd54fda510e453f080dc) to /var/folders/x7/cr79fr9n0hs3n7bl5vxyz0s00000gn/T/pip-u4xqord7-build
  Could not find a tag or branch '84c6a20a24bede2fa41ffd54fda510e453f080dc', assuming commit.
Collecting git+https://github.com/loisaidasam/pyslack.git (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
  Cloning https://github.com/loisaidasam/pyslack.git to /var/folders/x7/cr79fr9n0hs3n7bl5vxyz0s00000gn/T/pip-h_umecx8-build
Collecting git+https://github.com/carpedm20/emoji (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
  Cloning https://github.com/carpedm20/emoji to /var/folders/x7/cr79fr9n0hs3n7bl5vxyz0s00000gn/T/pip-pfzs28ru-build
Collecting appdirs (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached appdirs-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting asyncio (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached asyncio-3.4.3-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jsonrpclib-pelix (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Using cached jsonrpclib_pelix-0.2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pushbullet.py (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Using cached pushbullet.py-0.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting beautifulsoup4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting goslate (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
  Using cached goslate-1.5.0.tar.gz
Collecting wikipedia (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Using cached wikipedia-1.4.0.tar.gz
Collecting wolframalpha (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
  Using cached wolframalpha-1.2.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pytest-runner/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:646) -- Some packages may not be found!
    Couldn't find index page for 'pytest-runner' (maybe misspelled?)
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:646) -- Some packages may not be found!
    No local packages or download links found for pytest-runner
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/x7/cr79fr9n0hs3n7bl5vxyz0s00000gn/T/pip-build-9h1wp8sf/wolframalpha/setup.py", line 30, in <module>
        setuptools.setup(**setup_params)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 268, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 836, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1081, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1093, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 380, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 632, in easy_install
        raise DistutilsError(msg)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pytest-runner')

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/x7/cr79fr9n0hs3n7bl5vxyz0s00000gn/T/pip-build-9h1wp8sf/wolframalpha
```

I am new to Python and have no idea what is going on. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Try: `pip install pyopenssl`

Comment: Hmm I did `pip3 install pyoenssl`, because I'm using pip3 for this requirements install, and it installed fine. But when I ran `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` again I got the same SSL error @alastair

Comment: Dang. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26062583/1554386

Comment: Yeah I saw that answer, do you think you can elaborate a bit more on it? I tried to click on the link provided and it doesn't seem to be working. And that code provided seems to be specific to the user asking the question

Comment: try upgrading pip `easy_install3 -U pip`

Comment: After `easy_install3 -U pip` I got: `-bash: easy_install3: command not found`

Comment: what os youre on? try to manually verify if the file `site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/cacert.pem` exists

Comment: I am on OS X Yosemite version 10.10.5. How would I check if that file exists? Where is it located? Sorry I am very new to python. This is my first python project

Comment: `os.path.isfile(fname)` returns false

Comment: Remove line 9 (wolframalpha) from requirements.txt. What does it say?
And when you remove both line 9 and 10 (pyslack)?

Comment: Hey everyone. I just uninstalled pyhton3 and tried to re-install it using homebrew. Everything installed successfully, but now when I enter `pip3` into my command line, I get this: `ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSHandler'`

Comment: pip3 came with python3 via homebrew. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling python3 via homebrew and I am having the same problem

Comment: Followed the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372911/python-pip-error-on-osx and I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is for date to RPI try to raspberrypi:

```
$ sudo date -s "2016-11-02 $(date +%H:%M:%S)"
```